# Is it possible to post photos and update profile information with the Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an idea for a service I'd like to create. However, I'm not sure if it is possible. Forgive me if this seems like a duplicate question, but I've searched everywhere for this and I can only find outdated or loosely related answers.

With the current state of the Instagram API, is it possible to do requests that will post images to a user's feed, as well as update profile information? Specifically, I want to allow someone the ability to, from my third-party app, make a post to their feed and update the text in their bio

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible unless you are currently a Facebook Marketing Partner or Instagram Partner.

As stated on Facebook's Developer website:

```
The Content Publishing API is in closed beta with Facebook Marketing 
Partners and Instagram Partners only. We are not accepting new applicants 
at this time.
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing

Comment: Content publishing is now publicly available, with approval from Facebook. This allows you to post, but not update a user's profile information.